# Create Calendar Events Without User Authentication

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm writing an application that needs to create Calendar events on a user's Outlook Calendar. However, I will not have access to their passwords, and they will most likely not be involved in the workflow to enter them at any point.

Is it possible to create these events with the user being authenticated? If not, are there alternatives?

This is for an on-premise Exchange Server, not Exchange Online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use app impersonation, as long as the admin can add a service account and grant app impersonation.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the user can use his Windows Login to login to the Exchange Server, you can simply use that - if your application runs on the users machine under his account. EWS-managed-API does that out-of-the-box.
2. If not, you could create an additional user on the Exchange Server, who creates the appointments on his own account and invites everyone per email.

Comment: Sending invitations to appointments is not an option for me - events must be directly created on the Calendar. Also, it is not a guarantee (and also probably never true that the Windows user is the same as the Exchange account user in my case). I actually just came across [Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn722377(v=EXCHG.150).aspx), which (from my understanding) means that I can set up a user to be authorized to act as if they were another user. Would this be a good alternative?

Comment: I never used that, but if you can grant some special user access to all calenders in some easy way, that should work.